How to upload images using document.add_picture with autofit feature in a word file with python docx?
I've a working code which adds required images, applies border to it, saves it in a word file and then converts in a pdf file.
The problem here is that when I open the PDF in adobe acrobat, Some images have perfect border, but some don't (Bottom border disappear). Also some images appear bigger which have low resolution.
Below is the part of the code which I use to add picture in a word file
document_editor.add_picture(create_saving_path, width=Cm(15))
Whereas when I manually created a word file and paste all the images and apply border to all of them and then convert it to pdf.
All the images in pdf have perfect border with proper size.
Suppose if I don't use "width=Cm(15), all the images uploaded via code goes out of size.
Now all I want to know is that is there a way that when I use "document.add_picture" it autofits the pictures in word file?
I can't upload the code or images due to restriction.
But all I can ask you for is to create a script which takes 3 images with different resolution, add it in a word file, give them a border with 1 pt and then convert to pdf.
Once converted check whether in Adobe Reader the bottom border is showing or not.
